# Create lists with any two elements from a longer list DrRacket

Tags: list, scheme, racket, combinations, element

How can I generate serial lists by combining any two elements from a longer list, say with 4 elements?

For example, I want to get `'(1 2)`, `'(1 3)`, `'(1 4)`, `'(2 3)`, `'(2 4)`, and `'(3 4)` based on `'(1 2 3 4)`.

Answer (score 3):

The question asks for the 2-sized list of *combinations* of a given list. It can be implemented in terms of a more general procedure that produces n-sized combinations:

```
(define (combinations size elements)
  (cond [(zero? size)
         '(())]
        [(empty? elements)
         empty]
        [else
         (append (map (curry cons (first elements))
                      (combinations (sub1 size) (rest elements)))
                 (combinations size (rest elements)))]))
```

It works as expected when we specify that `size=2`:

```
(combinations 2 '(1 2 3 4))
=> '((1 2) (1 3) (1 4) (2 3) (2 4) (3 4))
```

Comment: This is a really nice answer, but I was surprised to not find it in racket, given its presence in both Python (itertools) and Clojure (math.combinatorics)

Comment: Agreed. There should exist a standard combinatorics module for Racket, using streams

Comment: Are you thinking what I'm thinking? ;-)

Comment: I wish I had the spare time :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution just as you specified (one function, one argument).  For input like `'(next rest ...)` the solution computes a result for `next` and then recurses on `rest ...` - using `append` to combine the two parts.

```
(define (combine elts)
  (if (null? elts)
      '()
       (let ((next (car elts))
             (rest (cdr elts)))
         (append (map (lambda (other) (list next other)) rest)
                 (combine rest)))))
> (combine '(1 2 3 4))
((1 2) (1 3) (1 4) (2 3) (2 4) (3 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want all the permutations as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13978863/445639).

Using his permutations function definition, you could do something like:

```
(permutations 2 '(1 2 3 4))
```

Comment: In this case the solution requires the combinations, not the permutations of the input list. The exact opposite of the situation described in the linked answer

Comment: Right you are. I always get those backward. Let's see if I can fix the example... Or you're welcome to as well :-)

Comment: Very nice. I think it will take me longer to understand it than it took you to fix.